# Realm - Can't use object after having been deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm, realm-list

I have a video player in my app. There is a list of videos in a collection view. If you tap on one of the cells, a new view controller appears to play the selected video. Also, you can cycle through all of the videos from the collection view in this new view controller because the entire list is passed.

The problem is:
When the user is in the `PlayerVC`, they can unfavorite a `Video`. If they do this, I delete the `Video` object from Realm. However, this causes a:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'`

***Basically, if a user is watching a video in `PlayerVC` and he unfavorites a video, I want them to still be able to watch the video for the time being.*** But when they leave the `PlayerVC`, the collection view in `FavoritesVC` should be updated and not show that `Video` any more.

When I delete a `Video` object I use Realm's `delete` method.

This is my code to hold a list of `Video` objects:

```
/// Model class that manages the ordering of `Video` objects.
final class FavoriteList: Object {
    // MARK: - Properties

    /// `objectId` is set to a static value so that only
    /// one `FavoriteList` object could be saved into Realm.
    dynamic var objectId = 0

    let videos = List<Video>()

    // MARK: - Realm Meta Information

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "objectId"
    }
}
```

This is my `Video` class which has an `isFavorite` property:

```
final class Video: Object {
    // MARK: - Properties

    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var descriptionText = ""
    dynamic var date = ""
    dynamic var videoId = ""
    dynamic var category = ""
    dynamic var duration = 0
    dynamic var fullURL = ""
    dynamic var creatorSite = ""
    dynamic var creatorName = ""
    dynamic var creatorURL = ""

    // MARK: FileManager Properties (Files are stored on disk for `Video` object).

    /*
        These are file names (e.g., myFile.mp4, myFile.jpg)
    */
    dynamic var previewLocalFileName: String?
    dynamic var stitchedImageLocalFileName: String?
    dynamic var placeholderLocalFileName: String?

    /*
        These are partial paths (e.g., bundleID/Feed/myFile.mp4,     bundleID/Favorites/myFile.mp4)
        They are used to build the full path/URL at runtime.
    */
    dynamic var previewLocalFilePath: String?
    dynamic var stitchedImageLocalFilePath: String?
    dynamic var placeholderLocalFilePath: String?

    // Other code...
}
```

This is my code to show the `Video` objects in a collection view (Note: I use `RealmCollectionChange` to update the collection view for deleting  and inserting cells):

```
/// This view controller has a `collectioView` to show the favorites.
class FavoriteCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: Properties

    let favoriteList: FavoriteList = {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        return realm.objects(FavoriteList.self).first!
    }()

    // Realm notification token to update collection view.
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

    // MARK: Collection View

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favoriteList.videos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FavoritesCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell
        cell.video = favoriteList.videos[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

    // I pass this lst forward to the PlayerVC
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let playerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerViewController") as? PlayerViewController {
            // I pass the videos here.
            playerVC.videos = favoriteList.videos
            self.parent?.present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Realm Notifications


    func updateUI(with changes: RealmCollectionChange<List<Video>>) {
        // This is code to update the collection view.
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the code to allow the user to play and cycle between all `Video` objects:

```
/// This view controller uses `AVFoundation` to play the videos from `FavoriteCollectionViewController`.
class PlayerViewControllerr: UIViewController {

    /// This `videos` is passed from `FavoriteCollectionViewController`
    var videos = List<Video>()

    // HELP: The app crashes here if I unfavorite a `Video`.
    @IBAction func didToggleStarButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let videoToDelete = videos[currentIndexInVideosList] /// Get the video that is currently playing
            realm.delete(videoToDelete)
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately I want the `Video` object that is unfavorited to be **completely deleted from Realm**. Just not sure how/when to do it in this case.

Any thoughts?

### Update 1

An option to solve this is to:

- Make an unmanaged copy of the `Video` copy, and use that one to power the UI of the view controller.

The way I see this possibly working is this:

- The `PlayerVC` will receive two `List`, the original one saved in Realm and a copy of this `List` to power the UI. Let's call the lists `favoriteList` and `copyList`.
- So inside of the `didToggleStarButton` we would do something like this:

Code:

```
/// This view controller uses `AVFoundation` to play the videos from `FavoriteCollectionViewController`.
class PlayerViewControllerr: UIViewController {

    /// A button to allow the user to favorite and unfavorite a `Video`
    @IBOutlet weak var starButton: UIButton!

    /// This is passed from `FavoriteCollectionViewController`
    var favoriteList: FavoriteList!

    /// A copy of the `FavoriteList` videos to power the UI.
    var copiedList: List<Video>!

    var currentIndexOfVideoInCopiedList: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super viewDidLoad()

        // Make a copy of the favoriteList to power the UI.
        var copiedVideos = [Video]()

        for video in favoriteList.videos {
            let unmanagedVideo = Video(value: video)
            copiedVideos.append(unmanagedVideo)
        }

        self.copiedList.append(copiedVideos)
    }

    // HELP: The app crashes here if I unfavorite a `Video`.
    @IBAction func didToggleStarButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Do the unfavoriting and favoriting here.


        // An example of unfavoriting:
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let videoToDeleteFromFavoriteList = favoriteList.videos[currentIndexOfVideoInCopiedList] /// Get the video that is currently playing
            realm.delete(videoToDeleteFromOriginalList)
        }

        // Update star button to a new image depending on if the `Video` is favorited or not.
        starButton.isSelected = //... update based on if the `Video` in the `FavoriteList` or not.
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is definitely tricky for a number of architectural reasons.

You're right in that you *could* simply remove the object from the `FavoriteList.videos` and then properly delete it from Realm when going to dismiss the controller, but you're right that if the user clicks the home button, or the app crashes before then, you'll end up with a headless video object. You would need to be able to make sure you can track that.

There's a couple of things you might be able to consider.

- Add an `isDeleted` property to the `Video` class. When the user unfavorites the video, remove the `Video` object from `FavoriteList.videos`, set that property to `true`, but leave it in Realm. Later on (either when the app quits or the view controller is dismissed), you can then do a general query for all objects where `isDeleted` is `true` and delete them then (This solves the headless problem).
- Since your architecture requires a view controller relying on a model that could be deleted from under it, depending on how much information you're using from that `Video` object, it might be safer to make an unmanaged copy of the `Video` copy, and use that one to power the UI of the view controller. You can create a new copy of an existing Realm object by doing `let unmanagedVideo = Video(value: video)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!! From the 2 options, option 1 (Add an `isDeleted` property to the `Video` class) seems easier but less safe (like you mentioned). For option 2, I'm not sure exactly how to pull that off in terms of using a copy to manage the UI (Note: I updated my question to show more data that the `Video` has - maybe now it’ll be easier to see if this is best option). Overall, which option of these 2 (or another option) would you go with? (I know it might be hard to choose exactly since you don't know the entire app, but just for this use case in the question).

Comment: You're welcome! Hmm, it's tricky. Option 1 requires running 'garbage collection' elsewhere in your app which might be a small hassle, but isn't too terrible. But since your `Video` class doesn't have any linking objects, it would be very easy to duplicate using option 2, which might be a bit cleaner and more self-contained. But if your view controller does need to do any save operations to the object (while it's not deleted), you'd then have to worry about making sure both the duplicate, and the original object get those changes. Either way, both are viable options. :)

Comment: Ok, took a while to respond because we were really thinking this over. One thing (I will accept your answer btw). Everytime a `Video` is favorited, there is a copying of files on disk with `FileManager`; also when a `Video` is unfavorited, the files are deleted and the `Video` from Realm. The `PlayerVC` does not use these files, but the `FavoritesVC` does. It seems to me that Option 2 might be best, but not sure how to do this favoriting/unfavoriting with an "unmanaged copy of the `Video` copy". Have you come across any sample code or small snippet just to illustrate this? Thanks again!!

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts on my previous comment ^^ ? Thanks! Anyways I will accept your answer now regardless. Thanks again for your time, appreciate it! : ) (NOTE: We gave it a shot and updated our question with what we think is how to execute Option 2 ((Also, when PlayerVC dismisses, our goal was that the user does not see the Video being removed from the FavoriteVC collection view.))

Comment: No worries! Thanks! Hmm, no I haven't seen any code for this sort of thing; it's a pretty unique architecture pattern. Like I said above, option 2 will only work if you don't plan to modify the data a lot. It's essentially 'caching' a copy of the original object so the original one doesn't absolutely have to stick around.

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll look more into both options, Option 1 might work better since there is a lot of data being modified. Thanks and take care! : )

Comment: Quick follow up, the only way I got this working with Option 1 is by converting the `List` to a Swift `array` and passing that forward to the `PlayerVC`. I still use the `List` for the FavoritesVC, but I convert it to an `array` to pass to `PlayerVC`. I think this makes a copy of the objects. If I pass the `List` instead, I start to get crashes with `Index out of range..` since I rely on the index of the list or array to determine what to play --- if I remove a video from the `List` then this is where the issue arises. Making an `array` seems to solve this. Any thoughts on this? thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother, did you see above comment ^^? Please let the know your thoughts, thank you!

Comment: Haha no worries, but it might be better to make a new issue at this rate. XD Uhhh, no, passing Realm objects to a Swift array won't make copies of them; it'll just keep them retained in memory for the duration of the array's lifecycle. Something doesn't sound right here, but I don't think it's something we can fix in Stack Overflow comments. ^_^;;;;

Comment: Loll I know what you mean : ) Um I'll try my best again to not create that `array`, if not then I'll create a new SO question/issue  (I'll probably link it to you). Thanks for follow up!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround solution. Check if it works.

```
 class PlayerViewControllerr: UIViewController {

          var arrayForIndex = [Int]()
          var videos = List<Video>()


          @IBAction func didToggleStarButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
               self.arrayForIndex.append(currentIndexInVideosList)     
           }

         @overide func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool){
              super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
              for i in arrayForIndex{
                 let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            let videoToDelete = videos[i] /// Get the video that is currently playing
            realm.delete(videoToDelete)
        }
       }
        }
```

Comment: I updated my question to show my model called `Video` which has an `isFavorite` property. Please take a look and let me know what you think

Comment: Thanks for update! : ) What if the user is watching a video and they unfavorite the video so that `var arrayForIndex = [Int]()` now has 1 value. If the user quits the app then `viewWillDisappear` would not be called. Then we would have to worry about persisting `arrayForIndex` in case of app failure or  do `realm.delete(videoToDelete)` in other places such as listing for when the app goes to background, etc. Not sure if this is right way to do

Comment: I think viewWillDIsappear will always be called.  I checked it now.

Comment: From my tests, if you press the Home button on the iPhone, then `viewWillDisappear` will not get called. Instead App Delegate methods get called such as `applicationWillEnterForeground` `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Since this is the case, I'm not sure if this solution fits nicely for handling every case - I don't know to be honest

Comment: I checked with many examples and code and i got that viewWillDisappear is called. Check by creating a new project and calling a different viewController from first one the way you did(by using storyboard reference) . And call the viewWillDIsappear func in the secondOne. I am sure it will get called.

Comment: I kind of see what you mean and tried it out. One issue is that when you return to the collection view in `FavoritesVC`, you can see the cell disappearing. This is probably because when deleting inside of `viewWillDisappear` from `PlayerVC`, it doesn't have enough time to delete without the user seeing it happen