# Realm - Removing and adding objects from List

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081852/realm-cant-use-object-after-having-been-deleted) since I may be doing something wrong.

I have a video player in my app. There is a list of videos in a collection view called `FavoritesVC`. If you tap on one of the cells, a new view controller called `PlayerVC` appears to play the selected video. Also, you can cycle through all of the videos from the collection view in this new view controller `PlayerVC` because the entire list is passed.

Everything works fine here.

The problem is when I want to favorite/unfavorite a video. From the question I posted above, I decided to use this from the answer:

> Add an isDeleted property to the Video class. When the user
>   unfavorites the video, remove the Video object from
>   FavoriteList.videos, set that property to true, but leave it in Realm.
>   Later on (either when the app quits or the view controller is
>   dismissed), you can then do a general query for all objects where
>   isDeleted is true and delete them then (This solves the headless
>   problem).

*I can only get this to work if in `FavoritesVC` when a cell is tapped, I convert the realm `List` to a Swift `array` and use this `array` to power the `PlayerVC`. If I don't do this, and I remove an object from the `List` and the I try to cycle through the `List`, I get an `Index out of range error...`.*

**The solution I have to convert the `List` to a Swift `array` and pass that to `PlayerVC` works but seems wrong when using Realm.** Best practice is to never do this conversion but in this case I don't know how to simply use the `List`

This is my code for the list:

```
/// Model class that manages the ordering of `Video` objects.
final class FavoriteList: Object {
    // MARK: - Properties

    /// `objectId` is set to a static value so that only
    /// one `FavoriteList` object could be saved into Realm.
    dynamic var objectId = 0

    let videos = List<Video>()

    // MARK: - Realm Meta Information

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "objectId"
    }
}
```

I convert the List to an array and create the PlayerVC like so:

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let playerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playerVC") as? PlayerViewController {

            // I convert the `List` to a Swift `array` here.
            playerVC.videos = Array(favoritesManager.favoriteList.videos)
            playerVC.currentVideoIndex = indexPath.row
            self.parent?.present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of the `PlayerVC`. This gets created when a cell in `FavoritesVC` is tapped:

```
class PlayerViewControllerr: UIViewController {
    // Array passed from `FavoritesVC`. I converted this from the `List`.
    var videos = [Video]()

    var currentVideoIndex: Int!
    var currentVideo: Video {
        return videos[currentVideoIndex]
    }

    // HELP
    // Example of how to cycle through videos. This cause crash if I use the `List` instead of Swift `array`.
    func playNextVideo() {
        if (currentVideoIndex + 1) >= videos.count {
            currentVideoIndex = 0
        } else {
            currentVideoIndex = currentVideoIndex + 1
        }

        videoPlaybackManager.video = currentVideo
    }

    // This is where I add and remove videos from the `List`
    @IBAction func didToggleFavoriteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        favoritesManager.handleFavoriting(currentVideo, from: location)     { [weak self] error in
            if let error = error {
            self?.present(UIAlertController.handleErrorWithMessage(error.localizedDescription, error: error), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the code to add and remove an object from the `List`:

```
class FavoritesManager {
    let favoriteList: FavoriteList

    init(favoriteList: FavoriteList) {
        self.favoriteList = favoriteList
    }

    /// Adds or removes a `Video` from the `FavoriteList`.
    private func handleAddingAndRemovingVideoFromFavoriteList(_ video: Video) {
        if isFavorite(video) {
            removeVideoFromFavoriteList(video)
        } else {
            addVideoToFavoriteList(video)
        }
    }

    /// Adds a `Video` to the `FavoriteList`.
    ///
    /// Modifies `Video` `isDeleted` property to false so no garbage collection is needed.
    private func addVideoToFavoriteList(_ video: Video) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            favoriteList.videos.append(video)
            video.isDeleted = false
        }
    }

    /// Removes a `Video` from the `FavoriteList`.
    ///
    /// Modifies `Video` `isDeleted` property to true so garbage collection is needed.
    /// Does not delete the `Video` from Realm or delete it's files.
    private func removeVideoFromFavoriteList(_ video: Video) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId = %@", video.objectId)
        guard let index = favoriteList.videos.index(matching: predicate) else { return }

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            favoriteList.videos.remove(objectAtIndex: index)
            video.isDeleted = true
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still hard to answer concisely since I'm still not sure what you want to happen when a user 'unfavorites' a video.

For the best user experience, I would assume that unfavoriting a video will still let it play onscreen, but once the view controller has been dismissed, or the next video starts playing, the video has then been completely removed from the `favoriteList` object. This means that even when it is removed from `videos`, the `Video` object needs to stick around until the user has explicitly dismissed it.

I'm guessing the reason why converting `videos` to a Swift array works is because even if the video is deleted from the `videos`, its reference remains in the Swift array, so the `currentVideoIndex` value remains in sync.

It should be possible to directly use the `videos` object, but since you're mutating it when the user taps the 'unfavorite' button, you can't reliably store the 'currentIndex' as that will obviously change.

In this case, it's probably better to work out which videos to play ahead of time, and then store a strong reference to them. That way, even if `videos` mutates, we can still intelligently work out where we are in the playlist and the upcoming and previous videos we will play.

The player view controller just needs the favorites manager and the current video the user tapped

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let playerVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playerVC") as? PlayerViewController {
            playerVC.favoritesManager = favoritesManager
            playerVC.currentVideo = favoritesManager.favoritesList.videos[indexPath.row]
            self.parent?.present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And the player will logically work out which videos to queue up, even if they get removed from the `videos` list later on:

```
class PlayerViewControllerr: UIViewController {
    var favoritesManager: FavoriteManager

    var currentVideo: Video? {
        didSet { setUpVideos() }
    }
    var nextVideo: Video?
    var previousVideo: Video?

    func playNextVideo() {
        currentVideo = nextVideo
        videoPlaybackManager.video = currentVideo
    }

    func playPreviousVideo() {
        currentVideo = previousVideo
        videoPlaybackManager.video = currentVideo
    }

    func setUpVideos() {
        let videos = favoritesManager.favoritesList.videos
        let index = videos.index(of: currentVideo)

        var previousIndex = index - 1
        if previousIndex < 0 { previousIndex = videos.count - 1 }
        previousVideo = videos[previousIndex]

        var nextIndex = index + 1
        if nextIndex >= videos.count { nextIndex = 0 }
        nextVideo = videos[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

This works on the assumption that the user 'may' end up deleting `currentVideo` from `videos`, but the user can't delete `nextVideo` or `previousVideo` until they've become `currentVideo` too. In any case, now that the view controller itself is strongly referencing these video object, separately from the index, this should hopefully make copying `videos` to a Swift array unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for answering!! This fixes the crash! However the experience isn't the same as with Swift array (unless I did something wrong). What's happening now: Let's say the `PlayerVC` has 2 videos. If you unfavorite one of them, that gets removed from `favoriteList` -> but now you can't cycle back to this while in the `PlayerVC` after you do `playNextVideo` because it is no longer in the `List`. The user experience with the Swift `array` is that: even if the video is unfavorited, you can still cycle and see it again even if it's not in the `favoriteList` while in `PlayerVC`

Comment: Sorry if explanation is somewhat limited in my question. But ultimately if the Swift `array` is a good option, I could just use that too if that is good?

Comment: No worries! Yeah, that was on purpose. Like I wrote above, I assumed once it was unfavorited, once the user navigated away, it would then completely remove itself. Ahh, so you actually wanted the video to remain in the video player's playlist until they dismissed it? Okay. Yeah, making a static copy of the `videos` object works well for that then.

Comment: Yeah sometimes I trim the details because if not, nobody reads a long question, but that hurts with explaining, again my apologies. Ok makes sense, I will use the Swift `array` then. I still don't understand memory that much so to be honest not sure how Realm mixes in with Swift very much, being that a `List` is a reference type (I think) and a Swift `array` is a `struct` (value type). Anyways I'm going with your suggestion. You're a legend, always fantastic answers!!